# Facebook in-app events log for IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-insights

I've added to in-app events to both of my apps - Android + iOS.

The issue I'm facing is that I see the word "Other" for the iOS devices (on the column "Client") on the event log table on the Insights -> App Events -> Overview -> the bottom table
Whereas for the Android I can see "Android".

Notice however that if I drill down for each event graphs I indeed see the separation between Android and iOS.

Anyone bump with this behavior? Why is that? Is this a bug on Facebook or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug on Facebook - anyway the mapping to the iOS works good - only the main log table is getting update with "Other" as the client.